# SpecFlow IObjectContainer: How to register and consume multiple objects of the same type?

Tags: c#, automated-tests, specflow

Here is my Hooks class in SpecFlow.

```cs
 public sealed class Hooks
    {
        private readonly IObjectContainer _objectContainer;

        public ConcurApiHooks(IObjectContainer objectContainer)
        {
            _objectContainer = objectContainer;
        }

        [BeforeScenario]
        public void BeforeScenario()
        {   
            var httpClient1 = new HttpClient();
            var httpClient2 = new HttpClient();

            _objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs(httpClient1, "client1");
            _objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs(httpClient2, "client2");
        }

        [AfterScenario]
        public void AfterScenario()
        {
            //TODO: implement logic that has to run after executing each scenario
        }
    }
```

I am wanting to register two HttpClients because they will contain different base endpoints, authentication, etc. Up until this point this is all valid and SpecFlow allows for it.

Where I cannot seem to get this to work is on the consumption of it in my Steps class.

```cs
    [Binding]
    public sealed class ApiSteps : Steps
    {
        public ConcurApiSteps(HttpClient httpClient1, HttpClient httpClient2)
        {

        }
    }
```

Is there a way to do this? I would think so due to you being able to name the instance you register, but I cannot seem to get this to work.

Comment: Why not create something like an HttpClientProvider that just keeps a dictionary of named HttpClient instances and register that with the DI provider.  Then when you need a specific client you could do something like provider.Get("namedHttpClientInstance").

Comment: Yeah, ultimately I think I might use an HttpClientFactory. That said, you could replace HttpClient with something else and still have the same question. The reason I asked this was because this was not the first time I needed something along these lines and SpecFlow allows you to name the registration so I thought there must be a way to do it. Could be wrong though.

Comment: Yeah.  I was just looking at the specflow code and don't see how it will resolve a named instance in the constructor. Not sure HttpFactory would work because it's just going to give you back a new HttpClient from a pool.  Sounds like you have 2 preconfigured clients you need access to.  Which is why I said Create a provider that instantiates them and put them in an internal dictionary by name.  Then pass that provider around.  Then resolve the client itself by retrieving the HttpClient instance from the dictionary.  Basically you are doing the resolution yourself.

Comment: That would solve my issue. However, I'm confused on the purpose of the naming functionality in the `objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs(object, "name")` if not to allow multiple instances of the same type?

Comment: Maybe the constructor argument names need to match the names you register them as with BoDi?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I tried that and it didn't work (that's what prompted the question)

Answer (score 3):

You can register like this

```
_objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<HttpClient>(new HttpClient(), "httpClient1");
_objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<HttpClient>(new HttpClient(), "httpClient2");
```

then in the constructor of another class

```
public Constrcutor(ObjectContainer objectContainer)
{
    var http1 = objectContainer.Resolve<HttpClient>("httpClient1");
    var http2 = objectContainer.Resolve<HttpClient>("httpClient2");
}
```